# What's the preferred way of rendering nested json in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've recently found the following code for nesting json in a rails app. 
And I wonder, what's the preferred way of doing this?

Should I use active model serializers or stick to the following code?

[git](https://github.com/superhighfives/list-of-ingredients/blob/master/app/controllers/drinks_controller.rb)

```
class DrinksController < ApiController
  ...
  # GET /drinks/:id
  def show
    @drink = Drink.find(params[:id])
    render json: @drink.to_json(:include => { :ingredients => { :only => [:id, :description] }})
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all going to depend on your use case. For example, if your app is mostly server side rendered HTML with a few javascript sprinkles, your current method maybe perfectly adequate.

However, if you are using a client side framework and using Rails mostly as an API endpoint you'll most likely want to look into a more robust solution that can better handle complex relationships and perhaps even presenter methods. As your app grows it will inevitably become more complex and `to_json` will quickly be outgrown.

[Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) is a great library for handling complex JSON rendering and worth looking into, if that's the case.